# CTI integration Service Now + Twilio

Tags: twilio, servicenow

I completed the CTI [integration](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-customer-service-management/page/product/customer-service-management/task/t_PhoneInstallationAndConfiguration.html) with Twilio. 
I am able to receive and place external calls. 
Based on the documentation, once Agent receives an internal call, it can only transfer to internal Agent. I need to either transfer to external party (Supervised transfer) or make a Conference call. Is this possible? 
If it is not, what other integration that is supported will allow me to do this. 
I currently don't have any Telephony system and we need agents to use Web Browser.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, that is an add-on built by ServiceNow. I would recommend contacting them with questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. I've done it within their Flex systems, not sure what CTI entails, but it sounds like they have the same limitations which is rooted in Taskrouter. You would have to make a custom button that extracts the customer callSid from the agent conference and sends that as a param to an endpoint that uses Twilio's REST API to update the customer call:

1. Make custom UI button to extract CallSid of the customer in the active agent conference
2. Hit an endpoint with the callSid as a param, and use Twilio REST API to update
   the callSid by passing in a URL, which is just issuing a redirect to another Twilio
   endpoint.
3. Make this Twilio endpoint respond with TwiML, such as a dial verb to the transfer
   party's number or whatever TwiML you want to respond with.
4. Be sure you wrap up and complete the tasks-- otherwise you won't be able to take on
   another task. Also in the callback urls for the redirect TwiML, be sure to specify the
   endConferenceOnExit events for your customer based on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for responding, which Web phone did you use?

Comment: I looked at the integration with Flex, this definitely will work for me

Comment: Using Flex, but am in the process of building a proprietary dialer application. Flex is an awesome Call Center application. You can't go wrong with it.

Comment: Also here's a relevant link to the Twilio API I was referring to: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-node-js